# Hyperlink EventArgs Can't Be Referenced

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get a hyperlink to function in WPF. Initially the hyperlink would render, but clicking on it would do nothing. I found that I needed to add a request navigate handler, and did so.

My XAML is:

```
  <TextBlock Margin="3,25,0,0">           
        <Hyperlink Name="Link" NavigateUri="{Binding Item2.TT}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.TT}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
  </TextBlock>
```

Code-behind is:

```
private static void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

However the code won't compile due to error:

> Error 1   Member 'ACME_WPF.MainWindow.Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

I don't understand what exactly I need to do to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the static keyword to get this to work. So

```
private static void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

became

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```